# Angular provider receives JSON but recognizes its content as none

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular8

I have two components that depend on a third component function to receive some JSON data.
The function that them both use is this:

```
getAllPosting(before, after) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log("url", environment.apiLogin + this.apiBase + localStorage.getItem('idEmpresa') + '/' + before  + '/' + after)
      this.http.get(environment.apiLogin + this.apiBase + localStorage.getItem('idEmpresa') + '/' + before  + '/' + after, {headers: {Authorization: this.oauthService.authorizationHeader()}})
        .subscribe((result: any) => {
            console.log("provider result", result)
            resolve(result);
          },
          (error) => {
            reject(error);
          });
    });
  }
```

On the first component, the *console.log("provider result", result)* statement shows this result:

[image: All the object fields and information is correct.]

However, on the second component, the highlighted *console.log* shows this result:
[image: The fields that we need, amountPaid and balance, keep coming as NaN]

It's does not seem to be a back-end problem since on the db all the data and the queries return the correct result. There are thousands of users but none of them have this problem, except for this current user.

This error is resulting to no data being show on the table, like:

[image: The fields that should show on the table are the same fields that are coming back as Nan]

I've tried requesting the data on different clients but none of them have this problem. It is exclusive of this one user.

Also, when trying to console.log the array using a forEach iteration, the correct information is showing. However, when trying to console.log the whole object, the main fields that we use for the table keep showing as Nan.

```
result.forEach(element => {
              console.log("foreeach",element.amountPaid)
            });
```

[image]

Comment: Hard to troubleshoot - however, I see there is a before and after variable AND a localStorage item that are all part of the URL. Could be an issue specifically on that client machine?

Comment: kind of need to see how the two components are receiving the information and what they're doing with it...

Comment: The real problem is that the console.log is on the provieder itself. The result doesn't even comes back to the component to be manipulated. On the provider the console.log shows different results for the sabe function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data that comes back from the `http.get` call is truly correct, there is a chance that the object that is returned from the service is later manipulated by the code that is triggered after `resolve(result)` is called.

So when you attempt to view the `result` object in the console, what you will see is what the result of that manipulation is, not what the object was during the `console.log` call. This would explain why you are seeing correct values during the `foreach` prints, as the console is printing number literals - not objects, however they are likely then changed by the code that gets triggered when the promise is resolved.

Hence, I would recommend checking the code that uses the `getAllPosting` result.

Comment: But even b4 the resolve(result) the console.log already showes up the object with the Nan fields.

Comment: What you are viewing in your console is the object **reference**, not the state of the object when it was called by ```console.log```. If you want to see what was inside the object when ```console.log``` was called, you should use the following:
``` console.log(JSON.stringify(result))```. This will print a string literal with the actual contents of the ```result``` object at the time ```console.log``` was called.

Comment: On the console.log with the JSON stringify function we can see the info on the object. However we already knew that by iterating the object with forEach.

Comment: So that confirms that the ```result``` object is correct before ```resolve(result);``` is called. Then it is 100% being changed later in the runtime. You will have to check what uses the ```result``` after ```getAllPosting``` is called.

Comment: But inside getAllPosting itself the console.log shows the data all wrong. Event before going back to the component that called it, the result is already wront.

Comment: But you have just confirmed that the data is correct when you use the following line ```console.log(JSON.stringify(result))```. Using ```console.log(result)``` will only show you what the result properties are after the other code in your component have finished using it.